# htaccess redirect using delimiters

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I did this .htaccess file to redirect everything in my site following the standard mysite.com/module/action

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|ttf|woff|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?module=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Its ok for example if I visit mysite.com/contact or mysite.com/contact/save but when I don't pass any parameter (module or action) I have a 403 error because it try to perform index.php?module=&action=

My question is how I check if the URL has or not slashs, because if I don't have parameters, I need to only goes to index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?:css|js|ttf|woff|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply its work fine, but I have other problem after this option.
If i visit the home page I had a 403 error yet. 
For example if I don't have module and action variables, how I only go to index.php ?

Comment: `DirectoryIndex` already does that. Try adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` at top of this .htaccess

Comment: unfortunatelly the error continue...

`
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?:css|js|ttf|woff|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
`

http://localhost:81/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11/data/localweb/mysite/index.php?module=&action=

Comment: So...I only navigate to home, form example http://localhost:81/mysite and its generate a local path not virtual/remote

Comment: My hyperlink point to http://localhost:81/mysite/ , but after click on it the .httaccess generate this http://localhost:81/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-DevSe‌​rver-14.1VC11/data/l‌​ocalweb/mysite/index‌​.php?module=&action=
The odd in this situation that its happens only in index / root folder, other urls, like mysite/x or mysite/x/y works fine

Comment: That is certainly not happening in the .htaccess I posted. Do you have some other rule as well? Did you try clearing browser cache?

Comment: Actually I agree with you, probably the problem it is in other part of the website after I take the current url to process. Thanks for your time and effort to understand the problem and help me. 
I will check exactly what is the problem, one thing that I notice is if restart apache the first execution run fine, the next one raise the error, so, probably not is the httaccess the problem.